# lexicographic closeness and subcollections

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'd like to create a nested database structure, where there is a predictable tree of collections under some root level documents. The root level documents won't have high read/writes. They are there to logically group collections/documents. Regular documents in the subcollections will have high read/writes.

Say I want to split out a general db structure listing farms by US state:

```
# ggid == google generated id
/states/
  CA:
    name: 'California',
    farms/
      ggid-1:
        name: 'Happy Valley'
  NV:
    name: 'Nevada',
    farms/
      ggid-2:
        name: 'Rancho Grande'
      ggid-N:
        name: 'Rancho N'
```

In the above, any document in `/states/$STATE/farms/` will have an auto generated id, but the ids for the states would use their acronym. These state documents won't ever have high read/writes, but the documents in the subcollections woud. For example So I might need high reads from `/states/CA/farms/87897arostinarst8y7`.

Would such a layout be prone to hotspotting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not see any effects of hot-spotting, as hot-spotting is dependant on the ID of the document itself and having similar names. IE: incremental names and multiple incremental fields at a high rate.

> Creates new documents at a very high rate and allocates its own monotonically increasing IDs.

> Firestore allocates document IDs using a scatter algorithm. You should not encounter hot-spotting on writes if you create new documents using automatic document IDs.

> Creates new documents at a high rate in a collection with few documents.